# Issue with MUI 5 DialogContent padding

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have migrated to mui v5 and have an issue with DialogContent. How can I overwrite this style from `MuiDialogContent -> styleOverrides`? Is any way to join class names?

Here is the source code location where style is applied:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/b265431f9a32ea726c5227821126fbc6424117d5/packages/mui-material/src/DialogContent/DialogContent.js#L41

Answer (score 2):

I managed to override it like that:

```
MuiDialogTitle: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        '&+.MuiDialogContent-root': {
          paddingTop: '20px !important',
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

So far cant find the better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's loot better

```
 MuiDialogActions: {
          styleOverrides: {
            root: {
              padding: '16px',
            },
          },
        },
```